# Non Fetch Request and managedObjectContext Error When Loading A TableViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, core-data

Here is my situation:

I have an app that loads a table from Core Data in the initial view of my app. Lets call it View1TVC.  AppDelegate.m is set up so View1TVC is the initial view.

Now in View2TVC, I am trying to load up the SAME TABLE (filtered in View1TVC) but the app crashes with the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An instance of
>   NSFetchedResultsController requires a non-nil fetchRequest and
>   managedObjectContext

The code related to loading up the table for both View1TVC and View2TVC is identical!!  It works in View1TVC, but not View2TVC.  Here's the View2TVC code:

```
 -(void)setupFetchedResultsController
{
     NSString *entityName = @"Task";
     NSLog(@"Setting up a Fetched Results Controller for the Entity named %@", entityName);

// REQUEST:
     NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entityName];

// SORT:
     request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor
                             sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" 
                                         ascending:YES 
                                          selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];

// FETCH: 
     self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request 
                                               managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                 sectionNameKeyPath:nil 
                                                          cacheName:nil];
     [self performFetch];
 }



 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
     [super viewWillAppear:animated];
     [self setupFetchedResultsController];
 }




 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell...

Task *task = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.textLabel.text = task.name;

return cell;
}
```

The app hangs specifically when it segues to View2TVC and reaches the SORT line of the setupFetchedResultsController method:

```
     request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
```

Anyone have any idea?  Does the error have to do with me identifying View1TVC as my default app in AppDelegate.m?  Here's the code in AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Override point for customization after application launch.
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
View1TVC *controller = (View1TVC *)navigationController.topViewController;
controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
return YES;
}
```

I'd GREATLY appreciate any insight anyone can lend! Thanks.

Comment: Going by the error message, I'd be curious what you see if you put `NSLog(@"Request: %@, Context: %@", request, self.managedObjectContext);` right before the "FETCH:".

Comment: The problem is it hangs at the SORT, before it gets to the FETCH.  But if I put a comment in before the SORT, it'll give me an error: cannot respond to -entity until used by an NSManagedObjectContext'

Comment: That all sounds fairly strange...both errors seem to have little to do with the code.  Can you log the value of self.managedObjectContext when you enter this method? (The other thing I'd be tempted to try is to wrap the entire content of the method in a @try/@catch block and see what exception -- if any -- popped up and what its call stack symbols looked like.)

Comment: I should have added that     NSLog(@"CONTEXT: %@", self.managedObjectContext);  yields a value of (null) and     NSLog(@"REQUEST: %@", request);  gives me the error: This fetch request (0x6a9fa60) was created with a string name (Task), and cannot respond to -entity until used by an NSManagedObjectContext

Comment: OK...then getting a reference to a managedObjectContext into View2TVC when it's created would be a good place to start.

Comment: How (and where) do I go about doing that?  In viewDidLoad with the same code I used in applicationDidFinishLaunching in my AppDelegate.m? (See my code just above in my posting.)

Comment: I wonder if I can only access my Core Data from my initial tableViewController (ie. View1TVC) and not View2TVC.  Might that be the issue?

Comment: Similar code wherever you create and display your View2TVC instance.  Assuming that's somewhere in View1TVC, it would be like `view2controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;`.

Comment: hmm, I'm not sure where I would add that. Maybe if i create a prepareForSegue method in View1TVC and put that line in there.

Comment: Sounds right.  I keep forgetting that people use storyboards.  :)

Comment: Thank you Phillip!  That solved the problem.  I really do appreciate your help!!  Yeah, this is my first time in using a storyboard.